# SQL query: only one dataset per specific attribut

Tags: sql, select, group-by, where-clause

I want to retrieve only one dataset per specific attribute (column value) from a database.
E.g.: you have a table like this:

```
restaurant district longitude latitude
---------------------------------------
deli meal  1        80.456    -56.89
perseus    1        80.879    -56.00
artica     2        67.7080   -69.89
tieus      2        67.00     -69.00
petera     3        89.00     -78.89
```

And you wish only one example for each district e.g.:

```
deli meal  1        80.456    -56.89
artica     2        67.7080   -69.89
petera     3        89.00     -78.89
```

How do I achieve this? Normally I would just group by district, but then I loose the other attributes. Thanks for all answers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve it, one is by using a subquery which separately gets the one record for every district. Since you haven't mentioned your RDBMS that you are using, this will work on almost all RDBMS.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  district, MAX(longitude) max_val
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY district
        ) b ON  a.district = b.district AND
                a.longitude = max_val
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee2f4/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ RESTAURANT ║ DISTRICT ║ LONGITUDE ║ LATITUDE ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ perseus    ║        1 ║ 80.879    ║ -56.00   ║
║ artica     ║        2 ║ 67.708    ║ -69.89   ║
║ petera     ║        3 ║ 89.00     ║ -78.89   ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
WITH recordList 
AS
(
    SELECT  restaurant, district, longitude, latitude,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY district ORDER BY longitude DESC) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
SELECT  restaurant, district, longitude, latitude
FROM    recordList
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80588/1)